# Is pgAdmin adding query time overhead?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, pgadmin

I just wrote a long question about what I did to optimize a rather simple query that takes much longer than I wish it would. I kept querying with pgAdmin. And then I made the query simpler and simpler until I ended up querying for the primary key of a newly created table with just 1 row in it.

```
create table perf_test (id bigint primary key);
```

and then queried:

```
select
  count(t.id)
from
  perf_test t
where
  t.id = 1
;
```

and the message output is:

```
Successfully run. Total query runtime: 66 msec.
1 rows affected.
```

I need to optimize a query that usually takes around 30-40ms when issued from my application. How can I experiment and measure the performance if the execution time in pgAdmin is already much higher for the simplest of all queries?

Comment: Counting is expensive under an MVCC architecture. Try selecting a single record using the PK!

Comment: counting one value takes long? ... I switched to just return the id and still the same execution time.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ To Verace's point, it probably adds an unnecessary operation to the query plan as opposed to just selecting the PK itself...but obviously that should be negligible here. OP why is 30ms too slow for you?...how often is this query ran over what timeframe?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  - my bad! I just glanced at it and thought it was a table count and jumped in (putting one foot in mouth at same time)!  Sorry to OP!

Comment: @J.D. thanks for the interest in my work, but analyzing the problematic query here would crash the entire question. But to answer your question: roughly 200k-300k times per day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, pgAdmin adds a lot of latency overhead.  I'm surprised you could even get it as low as 66msec.

The answer is pretty easy, don't use pgAdmin for things like this.

To try to figure out why a query is slow, you should use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the query.  pgAdmin does provide a way to do that, but IME it is strictly worse than just doing it through `psql`, or by using auto_explain to capture the plan into the log files.

Comment: "*a lot of latency*" - in my experience, connecting to a local development database in a docker container, there is barely any overhead. There is some extra overhead in relaying the results from the pgadmin python webserver to the frontend, but afaik that is not included in the measured query time.

Comment: @Bergi Using desktop mode on Windows 10, talking to a PostgreSQL running on the same Windows machine, the lowest latency I saw (as reported by pgAdmin itself, not by `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`) over a couple dozen attempts was 81ms, the typical was more like 125ms.  The same query run on psql in the CMD shell was reported as 0.3 to 0.6 ms by \timing feature.  I don't know what time pgAdmin's report includes or excludes, or what happens on other platforms, but this is entirely unsuitable for any tuning work.

Comment: Unless the desired end run time of the tuned query is well over second, then I guess it wouldn't matter if 100 ms was added to each attempt.  But it still is the wrong approach as just having a final run is much less informative.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking at the **wrong metric**.

> Total query runtime: 66 msec.

This resume in pgAdmin includes network latency and client overhead. Use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for a detailed query plan, and `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)` for minimum timing. The client does not matter for this metric at all, you get times from the server *without* network latency and client overhead.

See:

- [Get execution time of PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065976/939860)